# Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting error when running webpack with babel-loader

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-dom'
```

Here is my import statement

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' ;
```

I 'm using React 0.14.0

Comment: Could you run and post result from command npm ls ?

Comment: Have you installed react-dom package after upgrade?

Comment: react@0.14.0 is present in the list when i run npm ls

Comment: try run npm i react-dom

Comment: Okay , i didn't installed react-dom package . Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.14.x version dom rendering functions had been moved into `react-dom` package to be more universal.

> As we look at packages like react-native, react-art, react-canvas, and
>   react-three, it has become clear that the beauty and essence of React
>   has nothing to do with browsers or the DOM.
>
> To make this more clear and to make it easier to build more
>   environments that React can render to, we’re splitting the main react
>   package into two: react and react-dom. This paves the way to writing
>   components that can be shared between the web version of React and
>   React Native. We don’t expect all the code in an app to be shared, but
>   we want to be able to share the components that do behave the same
>   across platforms.
>
> The react package contains React.createElement, .createClass,
>   .Component, .PropTypes, .Children, and the other helpers related to
>   elements and component classes. We think of these as the isomorphic or
>   universal helpers that you need to build components.
>
> The react-dom package has ReactDOM.render, .unmountComponentAtNode,
>   and .findDOMNode. In react-dom/server we have server-side rendering
>   support with ReactDOMServer.renderToString and .renderToStaticMarkup.